# How to avoid CORS error for a React - GraphQL application

Tags: reactjs, express, graphql, camunda

I am currently trying to use camunda platform and in this concept I am building a react application to make a call to a graphQL api and perform some actions. So far, I have used the api with postman and does the job I want to, The graphql mutation is the following:

```
mutation claimTask ($taskId: String!, $assignee: String) {
    claimTask (taskId: $taskId, assignee: $assignee) {
        id
        name
        taskDefinitionId
        processName
        creationTime
        completionTime
        assignee
        variables {
            id
            name
            value
            previewValue
            isValueTruncated
        }
        taskState
        sortValues
        isFirst
        formKey
        processDefinitionId
        candidateGroups
    }
}
```

And the endpoint is

> http://{my_ip}:8082/graphql

which is set in a personal vm server. What I am trying to do now, is make the same request through the react app (apollo client). So far, I am getting a cors policy error:

> Access to fetch at 'http://{my_ip}:8082/graphql' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy

I understand that I have to configure somehow the uri that can be accepted by the server. My question is, since I am using an existing api should I do this from the express server (apollo server) configuration? Because so far every solution I found talks about implementing the api from the scratch, including defining the schemas.

I have concluded, that I should use the express server to create a kind of proxy so that the react app will hit the api through there but I cannot figure out how exactly is this implemented.

I know that this is a vague question, but any suggestion could be very useful.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

It is a best practice to not hit the GraphQL API directly, but to create your own facade, which exposes the functionality your front-end needs, possibly in a more use case specific way. This means connectivity only needs to be allowed server-to-server between the back-ends. It is more secure as you don't need to open the API to the public and it also solves the cross-domain challenge you have. Your facade will be exposed under your domain.

Here is a example NestJS client "Generating the Tasklist service":
https://docs.camunda.io/docs/apis-clients/tasklist-api/tasklist-api-tutorial/#generating-the-tasklist-service
On your express backend you would do something similar.

(This example uses a Java back-end with react, but I am guess you want JS:  https://github.com/camunda-community-hub/camunda-8-lowcode-ui-template/blob/main/src/main/java/org/example/camunda/process/solution/facade/TaskController.java .)